# Visual Basic won't print to textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

This is the code I am having trouble with:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim THR As Double
    Dim a As Double
    Dim r As Double
    THR = CDbl(0.7 * (220 - a) + 0.3 * r)
    textBox.Text = "Your THR is" & THR & " beats a minute"

End Sub
```

I want to get the information from `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` and then print it out to `TextBox`, but I am having a hard time understanding where to begin.

Comment: What kind of trouble exactly?

Comment: nothing will print to the textbox .. text in quotes turn to red

Comment: Please give your controls better names than "Label1" or "Textbox". They should be named after their purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you are intending on getting the values from your textboxes and putting it into `a` and `r`? Otherwise, those variables will just be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try

textBox.Text = "Your THR is"& THR.value &" beats a minute"

OR

textBox.Text = "Your THR is" & THR.value.tostring() & " beats a minute"

Possibly ..

textBox.Text = "Your THR is" + & THR.value & + " beats a minute"